# Label counts are often wrong

Tags: neo4j

I'm regularly building and deleting whole datasets using the batch importer (`neo4j-import`), but I often find that the cached counts on labels are wrong. For example, `MATCH (n:Label) RETURN COUNT(n)` returns 560, but `MATCH (n:Label) WHERE EXISTS(n.attribute_all_nodes_have) RETURN COUNT(n)` returns > 750,000 (which is the correct number).

This is especially problematic because it makes certain queries very slow. For example, `MATCH (a:Label1)-[r]-(b:Label2) WITH r LIMIT 5 DELETE r` took 14 seconds.

Deleting and rebuilding the dataset sometimes fixes this, but that takes a long time (10s of millions of nodes). Is there a way to fix the label counts in place?

FYI I'm on Neo4j 3.1.0 on MacOS Sierra 10.12.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counts after an import *should* be correct, however if they are not there's always the possibility to shut down db, delete the counts store `neostore.counts.db.*` and start anew. The counts will be rebuilt, however using the same functionality which the import tool uses to build the counts.

Comment: That's super strange yes. As always it'd be super nice with a reproducible test case (or in this case test data) :)